# Why ubuntu 20.04 live USB freezes on Asus vivobook with Ryzen 5 3500U?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 20.04, windows-10, asus

On Asus Vivobook with Ryzen 5 3500U and Radeon Vega 8 Graphics booting live from USB, Ubuntu 20.04 shows:

```
[  0.67475] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter
```

and freezes on first focal fossa screen.

Booting works with safe graphics mode.

Please suggest how can I overcome this problem and install Ubuntu 20.04 on the laptop along side the pre-installed Windows 10.

Comment: I suggest installing 20.10. The 5.8 kernel supports these cpu's a lot better. Or wait till 20.04.2 is released.

Answer (score 1):

You may probably need to add `radeon.modeset=1` to the boot parameters, I've an Acer A315-23 with your exact same APU and I need it nowadays even with the latest real time linux kernel on Manjaro.